# Why is absolute of Integer.MIN_VALUE equivalent to Integer.MIN_VALUE

Tags: java, integer

In java when I say `Integer i =  Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)`. I get the same value as the answer,which means `i` contains `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.
I have verified the same in C++ as well.

Why this behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read this in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.

I found the answer for this question and here is the explanation:
Computers work with binary arithmentic, the logic of `Math.abs` in java or the `absolute` function in any language is like below:

```
if(num >= 0)
    return num;
else
    return (2's complement of the num);
```

**Note : How to find 2's complement**

For a given number, we find it's 1's complement first and then add 1 to it. For e.g.
Consider our number to be `10101`
1's complement= `01010`
2's complement= `01011` (added 1 to the 1`s complement)

Now, for the sake of making it easy and clear, let us say that our Integer(signed) size is 3 bit, then here is the possible list of numbers which can be produced using the four bits:

```
000 --> 0 (0)
001 --> 1 (1)
010 --> 2 (2)
011 --> 3 (3) 
100 --> 4 (-4)
101 --> 5 (-3)
110 --> 6 (-2)
111 --> 7 (-1)
```

Now that this is signed, it means half of the numbers are negative and the other half are positive(The negative numbers are the ones with the first bit 1). Let us start from `000` and try to find its negative number, it would be the two's complement of `000`.

```
2's complement of `000` = 1 + `111` = `000`
2's complement of `001` = 1 + `110` = `111`
2's complement of `010` = 1 + `101` = `110`
2's complement of `011` = 1 + `100` = `101`
2's complement of `100` = 1 + `011` = `100`
2's complement of `101` = 1 + `010` = `011`
2's complement of `110` = 1 + `001` = `010`  
2's complement of `111` = 1 + `000` = `001`
```

From the above demonstration, we find that 2's complement of `111(-1) is 001(1)`, similarly 2's complement of `110(-2) is 010(2)`, 2's complement of `101(-3) is 011(3)` and 2's complement of `100(-4) is 100(-4)` and as we can see that -4 is the smallest negative number possible using 3 bits.

This is the reason why absolute of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: s/compliment/complement/g. Java uses two's-complement by definition, but C++ implementations are not required to use two's-complement. If it used ones'-complement, the above would not apply.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Thank you for suggesting the edit. s/compliment/complement/g . Its too late but its worth.

Answer (score 6):

There is an inherent asymmetry that is the root cause of this effect. The number of 32-bit bit patterns is even. One of those patterns is used for zero. That leaves an odd number of non-zero values. The number of positive values and the number of negative values cannot be equal because their sum is odd.

In the 2's complement representation used for Java integers, the number of negative numbers is one greater than the number of positive numbers. Each negative number other than Integer.MIN_VALUE corresponds to a positive number that is both its negation and its absolute value. Integer.MIN_VALUE is left over, with no corresponding positive int. Math.abs and negation map it to itself.

Answer (score 4):

> Why this behavior?

It is a mathematical consequence of the choice of representation used in all modern computers.

Here's an informal proof of why it *has* to be that way.

1. A signed binary number representation with N bits has 2<sup>N</sup> possible values; i.e. a set integers with an even number of elements.
2. Remove zero from the set.  The set is now has an odd number of elements.
3. Now remove all *pairs* of numbers of the form `{n, -n}`.  Each time we remove a pair of numbers, the set *still* contains an odd number of elements.
4. We are now left with a set that contains an odd number of integers for which `n` is in the set, but `-n` is not in the set.  Since the set size is odd, it cannot be empty; i.e. there is *at least one* number with this property.

In the representations specified by Java (and indeed used all other practical languages), integer types have 2<sup>N-1</sup> negative values and 2<sup>N-1</sup> - 1 values greater than zero.  The value that has the strange property is `MIN_VALUE`.  This representation is called [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

---

Strictly speaking, an integer representation doesn't have to have this anomaly:

- It is possible to have two zeros (-0 and +0); e.g. [signed magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation) or [one's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) representations.  (This invalidates step 2 of the proof: there are now 2 zeros to remove.)
- It is possible to exclude -2<sup>N-1</sup>; i.e. make it an illegal value. (This invalidates step 1 of the proof: the initial set now has an odd number of values.)
- It is possible to specify integer arithmetic so that (for example) negating MIN_VALUE raises an exception.  For instance `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` would throw an exception.

However, all of these things have significant performance implications, especially since modern computer hardware only supports twos-complement arithmetic natively.  They also have issues in relation to writing reliable integer codes ...

Answer (score 3):

Math.abs(int) docs says *If the argument is negative, the negation of the argument is returned.*  JLS 15.15.4. Unary Minus Operator says *For all integer values x, -x equals (~x)+1*.

-Integer.MIN_VALUE = ~Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1 = ~0x80000000 + 1 = 0x7FFFFFFF + 1 = 0x80000000 = Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: Special thanks for the concrete reference to the Java Language specification.

Answer (score 2):

You might expect that absolute value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` would be `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`, but this  value is out of primitive `int` size. And `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE` again. That's all.

Comment: Why exactly there is this special treatment of adding 1 with the Integer.MIN_VALUE and not other integers?

Comment: @dharam it is not a special treatment, I have tried to explain that absolute of Integer.MIN_VALUE is greater than the maximum integer that can be reperesented via int type.

Comment: @dharam In two's-complement arithmetic, you negate a number by taking its ones' complement and adding 1. It so happens that the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` are complements of one another, in a two's-complement system.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - I'm not sure what you're getting at (since your actual answer looks right), but `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` are not really complements (unless all you're saying is that they're the min and max values). Since you can represent 1 more negative number than positive number in 2's complement form, `Integer.MIN_VALUE` has a _magnitude_ one larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @DaoWen I meant that `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` are _ones'_-complements of each other.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - Ah, I see what you were saying now. I feel dumb. :-p

Comment: @Juvanis - I'm not the OP, but I am the only one who's upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way two's-complement number systems work. `Integer.MIN_VALUE` corresponds to 0x80000000. The standard way to negate it is to take its ones' complement (0x7FFFFFFF in this case) and add 1, and in this case it would overflow back to 0x80000000.