# How to resolve "Use the original value instead." SonarQube issue?

Tags: java, sonarqube

The call of the hashCode() method on File object , triggers this SonarQube issue :

> Use the original value instead.

How to resolve? Any help please?

```
File file = ......

.... = Math.abs(file.hashCode());
```

Update: the SonarQube description of the issue is [here](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2676)

Can I just write :  .... = Math.abs(file.hashCode()+1);

Comment: I checked the description of the issur in sonarQube, but is not clear how to resolve it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of your problem is the fact that Integer.MIN returns itself when taking the absolute value. This issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18565485/3230218).

The solution depends on what you need the value for. Your suggested solution (`Math.abs(file.hashCode() + 1)`) won't work, because if the `hashCode()` function returns Integer.MAX then that plus 1 is still Integer.MIN, so the final result could still be negative.

If you really need a positive hash of the file, you could do something like this:

```
final int hash = file.hashCode() == Integer.MIN ? Integer.MAX : Math.abs(file.hashCode());
```